# Java MyBatis Configuration AddMappers(String packageName)

Tags: java, mybatis

First of all, I have a java code like this :

```
Environment environment = new Environment("development",
                transactionFactory, dataSource);

Configuration config = new Configuration(environment);
```

Then, I tried to add the mappers, using addMappers(String packageName).
In that package, contains an interface of SQLMap

```
config.addMappers("com.test.mappers");
```

It works fine.

But when I have a reference to another project, and that project has a package named "com.testtwo.mappers", and contains an interface of SQLMap, and I tried to write this :

```
config.addMappers("com.testtwo.mappers");
```

My config does not load all of the interface SQLMap in the other project.

Do I miss something?

Thank you

Comment: Question is bit vague, please explain "reference to another project"

Comment: It is a web project. What I meant by "reference to another project" is, I export the other project into JAR, and put it in the web-project's WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: You use annotation based or xml based mapper files

Comment: I use annotation based

Comment: Are you using maven?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using mybatis-config.xml instead?

As documented in http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html, you should use mybatis-config.xml, inside there you can do something like this:

```
<mappers>
  <package name="com.testtwo.mappers"/>
</mappers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to put it simply
I want to add Mapper from package that is from another .jar

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

I use Reflections
So basically, I create an interface BaseSQLMap, and then make all of my SQLMap extends BaseSQLMap

The code for the reflections is :

```
Set<Class<? extends BaseSQLMap>> subTypes = reflections
                        .getSubTypesOf(BaseSQLMap.class);
```

Thank you very much all